# PHP Sqlite3 (not PDO!) transactions?

Tags: php, sqlite, transactions, rollback

Is it possible to use transactions (and rollbacks) with sqlite3 drivers in PHP? I havn't found infos here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

I dont want to use PDO...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 29):

Yes, transactions and rollbacks are possible even without PDO. Astonishing how difficult it is to find an example that explains how to accomplish this. Had to actually dig into some ready code to find out.

```
$db=new MyDB("database.db", SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE);

$db->exec('BEGIN;');

$stmt=$db->prepare('UPDATE table SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->execute();

$db->exec('COMMIT;');
```

*Source for logic: [sombra2eternity](https://github.com/sombra2eternity/inc.sqlite3.php), source for 'MyDB': [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php)*

Comment: The difficult part is when to `execute` imo. A lot of room for error in that regard. I would also suggest wrapping this in an `try` `catch` with `rollback` in the `catch`.

Comment: The [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

`Such transactions usually persist until the next COMMIT or ROLLBACK command. But a transaction will also ROLLBACK if the database is closed or if an error occurs and the ROLLBACK conflict resolution algorithm is specified. See the documentation on the ON CONFLICT clause for additional information about the ROLLBACK conflict resolution algorithm.`

So if you don't want to catch errors, the default behavior may work to rollback for you.  (Don't forget to `COMMIT` before termination if everything is fine!)

Answer (score 7):

Just execute the appropriate [SQL commands: BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Answer (score 1):

a short extension to F-3000's answer above. if you create your own class, you can write your own wrapper functions as well. for example:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {

  public function __construct(string $filename, int $flags = SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE, string $encryptionKey = '') {
    parent::__construct($filename, $flags, $encryptionKey);
    $this->exec('PRAGMA busy_timeout = 9900');
    $this->exec('PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"');
    // more pragmas ...
  }

  public function enum(string $table, string $key, string $value) {
    $enum = array();
    $sql = "select distinct $table.$key, $table.$value
      from $table
      where $table.$key is not null";
    if ($key !== $value) {
      $sql .= "
        and $table.$value is not null";
    }
    $sql .= "
      order by null";
    $result = $this->query($sql);
    if ($result !== false) {
      $row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
      while ($row !== false) {
        $enum[$row[0]] = $row[1];
        $row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
      }
    }
    return $enum;
  }

  public function begin() {
    $this->exec('BEGIN');
  }

  public function commit() {
    $this->exec('COMMIT');
  }

  public function rollback() {
    $this->exec('ROLLBACK');
  }

  // more functions ...

} // MyDB //
```